# Unreal crashes on build: unable to connect to the swarm

Tags: unreal-4, build-process

I am having trouble with Unreal engine 4. 22

After clicking on build, it CRASHES and says "unable to connect to the swarm"

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are asking many question withing single question and non of your question has proper description. provide some more information about your questions in the form of text or image or may be a video, so that community will understand your questions and they will answer.

Comment: Welcome, cogun. As Swati says, our model here on StackExchange is one question per post. An answer to "how to stop Unreal from crashing on build" generally won't be the same as an answer to "how do I make my grass look not creepy", so they should be asked on separate Q&A pages. I've edited your post to focus on just the first question - you can always post a second question with the next step you need help with. Be sure to include in your detail lots of description or screenshots of how you've set up your project, what output you're getting, and exactly how it differs from what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Swarm is part of the Unreal Engine which, when building lighting, connects to other computers running Swarm to use their spare processing capacity to reduce the amount of time it takes to build your level lighting.

You should have a copy of SwarmAgent.exe in you Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Binaries\DotNET

If you don't (and there have been reports that Windows Defender has been removing it recently), you either need to disable Windows Defender, go into your Unreal Engine Launcher, use the drop down and choose "Verify" or, if you have an earlier version of Unreal Engine on your computer, you can copy the SwarmAgent.exe from that engine version to your 4.22 DotNET folder.

Comment: i have checked SwarmAgent.exe is at it's correct position,and none of my anti-virus is blocking it .